# Matching specific Apache VirtualHost with regex

Tags: python, regex, apache-config

I am currently attempting to match a single Apache VirtualHost entry within an apache config file by the `ServerName` of the VirtualHost. I am doing this with python, using the `re` module.

Here's an example of the type of file that I am working with:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/dir1"
    ServerName eg1.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/docroot"
    ServerName desired.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/dir3"
    ServerName eg2.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to match the VirtualHost with a `ServerName` of `desired.dev`. So the match I am aiming for is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/docroot"
    ServerName desired.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

I assumed this would be fairly simple with a regex but I can't figure out how to do it. I currently have:

`<VirtualHost \*:[0-9]*>.*?ServerName +desired\.dev.*?</VirtualHost>`

But the issue with this being that it matches the very first `<VirtualHost...`, matches the `ServerName` and stops matching at the end of the closing tag of the desired VirtualHost.

I'm aware that there are probably python modules for parsing Apache config files but I do not wish to use anything from outside of the standard library. If attempting this with regex is a terrible idea, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost \*:[0-9]*>(?:.(?!</VirtualHost))*?ServerName +desired\.dev(?:(?!</VirtualHost).)*?</VirtualHost>
```

Try that, it uses a lookahead to ensure it's not running over any VirtualHost closing tags.

Comment: Hmm, that's not matching anything for me at the moment. I'm trying to figure out why but I'm not great with regex so I'm a tad lost.

Comment: Okay, I've got it. The second lookahead you've used doesn't seem to work, removing that gives:

`<VirtualHost \*:[0-9]*>(.(?!</VirtualHost))*?ServerName +desired\.dev.*?</VirtualHost>`

which is working for me. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, uhm.  Move the . around to the other side of that lookahead.  It was (correctly) failing to match the character right before the "</VirtualHost>", because it was followed by "</VirtualHost>".  It's sort of odd, but I encourage you to use the lookaround in both places.

Comment: Yep, that works. I am however getting weird behaviour with `re.compile()` matching this list: `[(' ', '\n')]`. Is this something to do with how you're 'capturing' the lookaheads?

I've never used lookaheads before so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Oh, Mhm.  What it's doing is capturing the group that I'm repeating, you can get around that by using a non-capturing group `(?: ... )` In the outermost sets of parentheses.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for. I've made this the accepted answer. Cheers man.